# How do I connect one IBOutlet to multiple classes?

Tags: swift, xcode8

I am trying to create a shop, in which you press a button, and it changes the amount of money on another view controller. The variable moneyAmount refers to the amount of money that the player has. I have a MainViewController, which has other buttons that bring you to different parts of the shop. The moneyLabel is a label that shows moneyAmount. I am trying to connect moneyLabel to the classes associated with the different parts of the shop so I can manipulate the label from there.

```
var moneyAmount = 1000000000

class MainViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var moneyLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func test(_ sender: UIButton) {
    moneyAmount = moneyAmount - 100
    moneyLabel.text = String(moneyAmount)
}

func refresh() {moneyLabel.text = String(moneyAmount)}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    moneyLabel.text = String(moneyAmount)
}

//Aircraft Shop
class AircraftViewController: UIViewController{

    @IBAction func C208(_ sender: Any) {
        moneyAmount = moneyAmount - 1200000
    }
}
```

I only inserted one section of the shop, the Aircraft Shop.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your `moneyLabel` outlet as an *array*:

```
@IBOutlet var moneyLabel: [UILabel]?
```

Now you can drag its circle to as many labels as you want, as long as they're all in the same view controller.